# How to config spring batch job run only 1 time when start application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, schedule

I created a Job using Spring Batch and use @Schedule to scheduling my job. But when I start my application, this Job will run outside @Schedule, it make 1 Job run twice time(in @Schedule and without @Schedule). How can I disable a Job run without @Schedule. It make my data is duplicate. **Resolved**

```
 [Async-1] [INFO ] o.s.b.c.j.SimpleStepHandler: Executing step: [syncTransactionMasterStep]
 [Async-1] [INFO ] o.s.b.c.step.AbstractStep: Step: [syncTransactionMasterStep] executed in 2s770ms
 [Async-2] [INFO ] c.a.b.m.j.s.SyncTransactionSchedule: Job running by using @Schedule
```

I have another problem when config JobRepository. I set tablePrefix but the list of tables required for spring batch is not automatically generated. Even though I added initialize-schema: always.

Comment: Does it help if you set the property `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`?

Comment: I have another problem when config JobRepository. I set tablePrefix but the list of tables required for spring batch is not automatically generated. Even though I added initialize-schema: always.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a separate problem that is unrelated to scheduling or the newly set property. If you agree, please create a new question. Please also share more details on the structure of your code. That my first comment helped you was mostly the result of a lucky guess.

Comment: Yep, I will create new question and show my code